# MVC how can i post a form without using a model

Tags: forms, model-view-controller

I would like to know how i could sumbit a form in mvc 4 without using a model binding to the view.

can some one please demontrate how? and how can i use that form in the controller?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is very easy to use a form without any sort of Model binding.

Simple set up your for using either `@using(Html.BeginForm()){ ... }` or plain html.

```
<form id="myForm" action="/ControllerName/ActionName" method="Post">

    <input type="text" name="foo" value="FOOOO" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" value="Baaaar" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

When you post this to the ActionResult, your action result just needs to be set up to accept a string value named foo and one named bar

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(string foo, string bar){
    // your code here
    return View();
}
```